# ImportError: The curl client requires the pycurl library Docker + Django

Tags: django, docker, amazon-sqs, django-celery, pycurl

I'm dockerizing Django 2.2 application and using `Pipenv` for environment management.
I want to use SQS as broker with Django celery.

I have installed the `pycurl` library using Pipenv

```
[packages]
...
pycurl = "*"
```

When I run celery locally

```
pipenv run celery -A qcg worker -l info
```

It works but when I run using docker image

```
docker run app:latest celery -A qcg worker -l info
```

It gives error

```
ImportError: The curl client requires the pycurl library.
```

The command in `Docerkfile` used to install dependencies

```
RUN set -ex \
    && BUILD_DEPS=" \
    build-essential \
    libpcre3-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev \
    " \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $BUILD_DEPS \
    && export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=nss \
    && pipenv install --deploy --system \
    \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false $BUILD_DEPS 
    \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Complete error log

```
[2020-05-25 17:16:22,216: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: ImportError('The curl client requires the pycurl library.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/__init__.py", line 20, in get_client
    return hub._current_http_client
AttributeError: 'Hub' object has no attribute '_current_http_client'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 205, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 369, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 318, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 599, in start
    c.loop(*c.loop_args())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 83, in asynloop
    next(loop)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/hub.py", line 301, in create_loop
    item()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 170, in __call__
    return self.throw()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 167, in __call__
    retval = fun(*final_args, **final_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/SQS.py", line 390, in _schedule_queue
    queue, callback=promise(self._loop1, (queue,)),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/SQS.py", line 406, in _get_bulk_async
    return self._get_async(queue, maxcount, callback=callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/SQS.py", line 416, in _get_async
    qname, count=count, connection=self.asynsqs(queue=qname),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/SQS.py", line 566, in asynsqs
    region=self.region
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/aws/sqs/connection.py", line 27, in __init__
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/aws/connection.py", line 194, in __init__
    **http_client_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/aws/connection.py", line 151, in __init__
    self._httpclient = http_client or get_client()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/__init__.py", line 22, in get_client
    client = hub._current_http_client = Client(hub, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/__init__.py", line 13, in Client
    return CurlClient(hub, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/curl.py", line 43, in __init__
    raise ImportError('The curl client requires the pycurl library.')
ImportError: The curl client requires the pycurl library.
```

Comment: You either did not install pycurl or installed it into a localized environment that isn't used by the code producing the error.

Comment: I installed it in Pipenv environment. I'm using same environment lock fike to install in docker. all other dependencies installed are working fine.

Comment: What are the paths to pycurl files after installation?

Comment: it's in the sites-available directory. But in Dockerfile I'm installing it again using `Pipenv install`  so it must be giving there in the python's sites-available directory as well inside the container.

Comment: So, is the installation directory wrong or the referenced directory wrong?

Comment: I couldn't understand what path you are talking about. Of course, the paths will be different in a docker container and local development machines. I executed `pip list` inside the docker and it shows the list of installed libraries including `pycurl 7.43.0.5` systemwide (no environment is used in the Docker container).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was with the `libcurl4-nss-dev libssl-dev` installation.

In the following installation script

> ````
> RUN set -ex \
>     && BUILD_DEPS=" \
>     build-essential \
>     libpcre3-dev \
>     libpq-dev \
>     libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev \
>     " \
>     && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $BUILD_DEPS \
>     && export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=nss \
>     && pipenv install --deploy --system \
>     \
>     && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false $BUILD_DEPS 
>     \
>     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* ```
> ````

The `libcurl4-nss-dev libssl-dev` installation is removed after the `Pipenv install`. So the package library couldn't be located.

After separating installation of `libcurl4-nss-dev libssl-dev` works for me.

```
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libcurl4-nss-dev libssl-dev
```

Comment: i use pipenv in the docker container and running this install before the pipenv install command solved the issue

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same error and this worked for me: `pip install celery[sqs]`

Comment: Solved my issue.

> For the Amazon SQS support you have to install additional dependencies. You can install both Celery and these dependencies in one go using the celery[sqs]

src: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/sqs.html